# Invalid default value for 'id' - Django project

Tags: python, django

When I try to migrate I get this error **Invalid default value for 'id'**
And in my dictionary I have no 'id' fields

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
  code=models.SlugField(max_length=70,unique=True)
  designation=models.CharField(max_length=255)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.article.code
```

views.py

```
from .models import Product

def viewproduct(request):
   products={'message':'passe','my_product':[{'code':'mlkk','designation':'toto'}, 
            {'code':'molo','designation':'patate'},...]}
   all_products=products['my_product']
   for product in all_products:
     object_product=Product(code=product['code'],designation=product['designation'])
     object_product.save()
```

Noted that my dictionary contains several products

Comment: looks like you previously had an id field which is now non-existent. check your migration file and remove whatever you set default to. If you don't know how migration file works, it's best to delete your database (if in dev environment) as well as any non- (____init____.py) file in the migrations folder

Comment: Thank you I have emptied the previous migrations and it works now